# Changing Background Image CSS Property Based on image selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on something I have not done before and wanted to see if anyone knows of existing jsjfiddle or something I can research/review to learn how to accomplish this.

The below image attachment shows what I am trying to create. I have the HTML/CSS in place as seen here:

```
<div class="container-fluid featured-artist">
  <div class="col-lg-3 artist-bio pull-right">
    <h4>JOHN DOE</h4>
    <h6><em>Artist Bio</em></h6>
    <hr>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p class="artist-link text-right"><em><a href="#">View all work from this artist</a></em></p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 artist-photo"> <img src="../html/img/ER 1 (original).png" class="img-responsive" /></div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 artist-photo"> <img src="../html/img/ER 1 (original).png" class="img-responsive" /> </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 artist-photo"> <img src="../html/img/CG 7 (original).png" class="img-responsive" /> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 artist-photo"> <img src="../html/img/ER 4 (original).png" class="img-responsive" /> </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 artist-photo"> <img src="../html/img/ER 2 (original).png" class="img-responsive" /> </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 artist-photo"> <img src="../html/img/other artists_F.png" class="img-responsive" /> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Right now the large image is a background property of the featured-artist class and my goal is to change that property if any of the 6 images on the right are selected. So if one image is selected, it changes the background image of the "featured-artist" css class.

If there is a jsfiddle that I can study or a tutorial, please send my way!

[Click To See What I am trying to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNVx8.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:-

**jQuery**

```
$('.artist-bio img').on('click',function(){
    var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');
    $('.featured-artist').css('background-image','url('+imgSrc+')');
});
```

If you are using separate images for thumbnail and background, you can set the large image paths to a data attribute on the `img` elements and then use that instead of their `src` attributes. Like so:-

**HTML**

```
<img data-src="path/to/large/img" src="path/to/thumbnail" alt="" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.artist-bio img').on('click',function(){
    var imgSrc = $(this).data('src');
    $('.featured-artist').css('background-image','url('+imgSrc+')');
});
```

Comment: I'm working with this code you provided but can't seem to get it to work. Is it right to target the artist-bio class rather than the artist-photo class that I have right before calling the image via HTML?

Comment: Sorry can't figure out how to edit comment...

Also, I am fairly new to javascript/jquery but my stylesheet is external, is that going to cause a problem or can js access all CSS once the page is rendered? Not entirely sure. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: @MichaelJFroseth Both should work since your `img` elements are descendants of both classes. Try using `artist-photo img` or just `img` if you want to test it out. And yes, jQuery can access all DOM elements and CSS classes if the stylesheet and the script are being loaded into the page.

Comment: Thanks for that. For whatever reason I can't seem to get that to work. Do you think I have to have full image paths? I wouldn't think so, but just trying to figure this out myself. If you're up to look at it and if it's any help the HTML file I am developing can be found here for reference http://michaelfroseth.com/clients/postedprints/html/index.html

Comment: @MichaelJFroseth I saw your page. You are calling the script in the `<head>` whereas jQuery is defined at the bottom of the body. You need to put the script after jQuery has been included.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').click(function(){
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        if(src == '../html/img/ER 4 (original).png'){
            $('.featured-artist').css('background-color','red');
        }else if(src == '../html/img/ER 2 (original).png'){
            $('.featured-artist').css('background-color','black');
        }
        // and so on
    });
});
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```